# Add new register automatic according date time

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i make an example for easy explain the question>>
I have 2 tables "LOAN" and "FINE"
Attributes of LOAN are: IDLoan(INT), IDUser(INT), IDBook(INT), Date(DATETIME).
Attributes of FINE are: IDFine(INT), IDLoan(INT), Date(DATETIME).
I want my program create the new register automatically in table "FINE", if it has any LOAN DATA that is expired of date(loan 3 days only).

1)... How can i do it to increase DATE of LOAN automatic?...
Do i need to update this attribute constantly??

2)i know, i need to do this for condition>>

```
    var LOANS = from loan in db.Loan select loan;
    LOANS = LOANS.Where(s=>s.Date.Contains(DATE.NOW));
    IF(LOANS!=NULL)
    and..... Create REGISTER IN TABLE FINE.....etc.
```

have some example??

thanks all!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to create a [SQL Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx) that runs every x amount of time and checks the LOAN table for expired records and creates a record in the FINE table if they haven't been created yet.

No need to update anything inside the LOAN table, just create a Stored Procedure that the Job will run, inside the Stored Procedure you can put something like

```
INSERT INTO FINE (IDLoan, Date)
SELECT IDLoan, GETDATE()
FROM LOAN L
LEFT JOIN FINE F ON F.IDLoan = L.IDLoan
WHERE (L.Date >= DATEADD(DD,-3,GETDATE()) AND F.IDLoan IS NULL
```

Obviously this will vary according to your business rules, in this case the query inserts records into the FINE table for all Loans with a date older than 3 days as of now that have not been added previously.

All you need to do is specify how often the job will run and it will take care of this without you needing to create any triggers or constraints in the tables.